# Chevrolet Matiz doesn't start first time in day

Tags: engine, electrical, starting

## I have a 2008 Chevrolet Matiz car, 3-cylinder 0.8L engine with the following symptoms:

1. Start hard the first start of the day (after 10-12 hours) then start each time from the first, if the interval is shorter 1-2-3 hours.

- the first key only spins the engine
- the second key, spins and starts, but fails.
- the third key, starts moving (stammers) and dies after 10-15 seconds
- the fourth key, starts the automatic shock, holds it for 40 seconds and stops the engine
- the fifth key, it starts and I let it go for 1 minute, I can't go on the road immediately because it doesn't have acceleration, the pedal is dead.
  On the exhaust, it only smells of gasoline 1 minute after it has started well, but it does not emit any smoke.

I poured injector cleaning solution into the tank.
I cleaned the injectors with carburetor spray
The ECM has no active or pending errors.

2. on the go when the accelerator pedal is constant at 2000-2300 rpm (50-60km / hour) in the city. a split second flashes in my nose. It's as if the power supply is cut off or it's too much fuel and it drowns.

I mention that I also cleaned the throttle.

- I didn't find any fake air
- I changed the TPS and IAC sensor with new ones
- Changed spark plugs + plugs + ignition coil

What advice do you have for me to try again?

Thank you

Comment: Hook a fuel pressure gage to it. Turn the key to on position (do not crank). The fuel pump should run for a couple of seconds then turn off. The gage should be at proper pressure and stay there for several minutes. If it goes down fairly quick, you are losing pressure to a leaking pump, fuel line or injector(s). If the pressure drops quickly, turn the key to on position and clamp fuel line before it drops too far. If the fuel pressure continues to drop, you probably have leaking injectors. If it doesn't drop you probably have leaking lines or pump. Leaking injectors also should trigger a code.